# Sometimes postgres does not return records when queried remotely from JDBC Client

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

```
  public static ArrayList<String[]> getDailyRecords () throws ClassNotFoundException {
    ArrayList<String[]> list=new ArrayList<String[]> ();
    String[] header = {"City", "Location", "Asset", "Number of Alerts", "Time spent in alerts", "Last seen temparature", "Limit"};
    list.add (header);
    String myDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    Class.forName (myDriver);
    try( Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection( ApplicationSettings.DATABASE_URL, ApplicationSettings.DATABASE_USER, ApplicationSettings.DATABASE_PASSWORD);
        Statement st = conn.createStatement ();) {
        conn.setAutoCommit (true);
        ResultSet rs=null;
        st.setFetchSize (200);
        String dailyQuery="select * from sch.reports();";
        rs= st.executeQuery (dailyQuery);
        while (rs.next ()) {
            String[] ar = new String[7];
            ar[0] = rs.getString ("location");
            ar[1] = rs.getString ("sublocation");
            ar[2] = rs.getString ("zone");
            ar[3] = rs.getString ("total_count");
            ar[4] = rs.getString ("period");
            String temp = rs.getString ("temparature");
            ar[5] = temp;

            list.add (ar);
        }
        conn.close ();
        st.close ();
        rs.close ();
    }catch(Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace ();
    }catch(Error e){
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
    finally {
        if(list.size ()==1){
            System.out.println ("NO records found");
        }else{
            System.out.println ("Foudn some records");
        }
        return list;
    }
```

I have a sql function, which does return records when queried locally from postgres clients. I invoke this function at scheduled timings from a java application. This worked fine for few months. But all of sudden, st.executeQuery() returning empty result set occasionally. Like 4 out of 10 attempts of executeQuery() in a day return empty resultset.

**Things I have tried out:**

- Made sure query returns some records always. It should return 60 records.
- Captured Errors,Exceptions. There were no errors seen.
- Made sure JDBC connection is closed.
- Debugged Postgres JDBC driver classes. Found that in cases when resultset is empty, data was not received from postgres data stream.

can size of data in tables influence query response?

Any help is kindly appreciated!

Update: SQL function definition added.

```
   DECLARE
    exception_error_code  text;
    exception_message     text;
    exception_detail      text;
    exception_hint        text;
    exception_context     text;
BEGIN

 RETURN QUERY

select l.name as location,sl.name as sublocation,z.name as zone,al.lim as lim,count(al.id) total_count,sum(al.timestamp_to-al.timestamp_from) period,t2.temperature  temparature  
                         from      
                         map.location l     

                         left join     
                         map.sub_location sl     
                         on l.id=sl.location_id     

                         left join     
                         map.zone z     
                         on sl.id=z.sub_location_id     

                         left join     
                         map.subzone sz     
                         on z.id=sz.zone_id     

                         inner join      
                         (select *,(info::json -> 'breach_type')::text as lim from alr.live where date(timestamp_from)= date(now() +   INTERVAL '5 hours 30 minutes')) al     
                         on sz.id= al.sub_zone_id     

                         left join     
                         (select subzone_id,max(nd_timestamp) as nd_timestamp from tel.temperature_sh group by subzone_id) t1     
                         on al.sub_zone_id=t1.subzone_id     

                         left join     
                         tel.temperature_sh t2     
                         on t1.subzone_id=t2.subzone_id     
                         and t1.nd_timestamp=t2.nd_timestamp     

                         group by l.name ,sl.name,z.name,t2.temperature , al.lim    
                         order by l.name ,sl.name,z.name;

-- if something "breaks" do the following
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    get stacked diagnostics
        exception_error_code  = RETURNED_SQLSTATE
        ,exception_message    = MESSAGE_TEXT
        ,exception_detail     = PG_EXCEPTION_DETAIL
        ,exception_hint       = PG_EXCEPTION_HINT
        ,exception_context    = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT
    ;

    -- log exception for debugging
    PERFORM public.insert_db_exception(
        exception_error_code
        ,exception_message
        ,exception_detail
        ,exception_hint
        ,exception_context
    );
END;
```

Comment: You've asked a database question without even showing us what the query is.  Do you expect someone will be able to help you?

Comment: Updated! It's actually a sql function. I'm sure it does returns records all the time.

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the function.

Comment: Updated function definition.

Comment: Size of the tables definitely have an influence - Can you give me the following details?
Enable timing (`\timing`) and give the time taken by the query to execute.
Also, can you run `explain analyze` on the statement

Comment: Function Scan on daily_reports

(cost=0.25..10.25 rows=1000 width=184) (actual time=1678.609..1678.613 rows=46 loops=1)
   
  Planning time: 0.033 ms
  
  
 Execution time: 1678.640 ms


Time: 1679.057 ms (00:01.679)